# How to retrieve callchain from ring buffer in perf_event_open for PERF_RECORD_SWITCH?

Tags: c++, profiling, perf

In the ring buffer, can we retrieve the callchain only for `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` or it can be done for other record types as well?

The man page of `perf_event_open` only explictly states the callchain to be available for `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE`. I am particularly interested getting the callchain for `PERF_RECORD_SWITCH` to get the stack trace for when my program is context switching in and out. I've tried a method of reading the callchain from the buffer, but seeing the addresses returned, it looks incorrect.

```
size_t index = mapping->data_tail; //mapping is the pointer to the ring buffer

uintptr_t base = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(mapping) + PageSize;
size_t start_index = index % DataSize;
size_t end_index = start_index + sizeof(struct perf_event_header);

memcpy(buf, reinterpret_cast<void*>(base + start_index), sizeof(struct perf_event_header));

struct perf_event_header* header = reinterpret_cast<struct perf_event_header*>(buf);

uintptr_t p = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(header) + sizeof(struct perf_event_header)

// Only sampling PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN
uint64_t* base = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(p);
uint64_t size = *base; // Should be callchain size
base++;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << *base << endl; // prints the addresses in the callchain stack
}
```

The 2 main issues with the output I am getting using this snippet are that : 
1. All `PERF_RECORD_SWITCH` have the same callchain. Which should be extremely unlikely.
2. The output is not consistent across multiple runs. The callchain size keeps varying from 0 (mostly) to 4,6, 16 and sometimes a very big (undefined) number.

Answer (score 0):

The callchain is only available for `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` events.

When reading the different record types, you should follow the `struct` definitions from [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) rather than just trying to access individual fields by pointers, i.e.,

```
struct perf_record_switch {
    struct perf_event_header header;
    struct sample_id sample_id;
};
```

And then cast the whole event `reinterpret_cast<struct perf_record_switch*>(header)`

Specifically the layout of the sample type is highly dependent on the configuration and may include multiple dynamically sized arrays which can prevent using a static struct.

Technically, you can collect callchain from switching events by using the `sched:sched_switch` tracepoint sampling event. This results in `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` events. However, your might not always see useful information but mainly in-kernel scheduling details.

Comment: How does perf record create a call-graph then for context-switches? perf record -g -e cs ./a.out and then perf report gives a call-graph percentage wise. Or is that something else?

Comment: The `cs` event uses `type=PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, config=PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES`. This also works with `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` events. The `sched:sched_switch` tracepoint has the advantage of including the switched-from and switched-to pids, as do `PERF_RECORD_SWITCH_CPU_WIDE` events.

Comment: Okay. But how do I emulate getting the callgraph using `perf_event_open` for `sched:sched_switch` or `cs` like `perf record -g`? Because `PERF_RECORD_SWITCH` samples are created during switch events. Do `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` have anything to do with context switches?

Comment: When calling `perf_event_open`, you use a `struct perf_event_attr` which includes `type=PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE, config=PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES`or `type=PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, config=(/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/id)`.